# Is there is any drupal module available to support both video and image?

Tags: drupal, module, media

I'm new to drupal, I want something like this, is there is any module supporting both video and picture, please suggest me how to achieve this!!!

[image: Drupal Module in eu.square-enix.com]

Comment: Not a Drupal guy, but it seems like a slider, most sliders out there can embed video and other contents.

Comment: Although if you put the link of the web page you took the screenshot, we may can help you as we see the source. There must be copyright or something in the source code.

Comment: Here is the link: [Hitman](http://eu.square-enix.com/en/games/hitman-absolution) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Module which provides your required functionality is [Dynamic display block](http://drupal.org/project/ddblock) module.

But there are other module such as [Media: Flickr](http://drupal.org/project/media_flickr) and [MediaFront](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following lightbox modules.

http://drupal.org/node/266126